# How can I stop my game from generating a new number while it's running?

Tags: python, random

I'm a beginner python developer. I've been experimenting with the random module and decided to create a guessing game. Problem is, Whenever the user inputs a guess, a new number is generated.
You can find this in the "run" loop. Here's the code.

```
import random
from time import sleep

print("""                                        Number Guessing Game
        Type 'Quit' To Exit The Game
Choose a Level:
    (1)Easy
    (2)Medium
    (3)Hard
""")

run = True

def play_game():    
    play_game.choice = input("> ")

    print("\nGuess The Number!\n")

    return play_game.choice

play_game()

while run:
    if play_game.choice == "1":
        r = random.randint(1, 10)

        guess = int(input("> "))

        if guess == r:
            print("You Won!")

            break

        elif guess > r:
            print("Too High!\nGuess Again.")

        elif guess < r:
            print("Too Low!\nGuess Again.")

    elif play_game.choice == "2":
        r = random.randint(1, 50)
            
        print("\nGuess The Number!")

        if r == guess:
            print("You Won!")

            break

        elif guess > r:
            print("Too High!\nGuess Again.")

        elif guess < r:
            print("Too Low!\nGuess Again.")

    elif play_game.choice == "3":
        r = random.randint(1, 100)

        print("\nGuess The Number!\n")

        if r == guess:
            print("You Won!")

            break

        elif guess > r:
            print("Too High!\nGuess Again.")

        elif guess < r:
            print("Too Low!\nGuess Again.")

    elif play_game.choice.upper() == "QUIT":
        print("See You Later!")

        sleep(1)

        break

    else:
        print("Unknown Command!\nTry Again")
```

Could you please help me figure out what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable called `generated` and only generate it if it is false. When you generate your number, set it to true

Your code:

```py
run = true
generated = false

while run:
    if play_game.choice == "1":
        if not(generated):  # ADD THIS
            r = random.randint(1, 10)
            generated = true # ADD THIS

        print(r)

        guess = int(input("> "))

        if guess == r:
            print("You Won!")

            break

        elif guess > r:
            print("Too High!\nGuess Again.")

        elif guess < r:
            print("Too Low!\nGuess Again.")

    elif play_game.choice == "2":
        if not(generated):
            r = random.randint(1, 50)
            generated = true

        print("\nGuess The Number!")

        if r == guess:
            print("You Won!")

            break

        elif guess > r:
            print("Too High!\nGuess Again.")

        elif guess < r:
            print("Too Low!\nGuess Again.")

    elif play_game.choice == "3":
        if not(generated):
            r = random.randint(1, 100)
            generated = true

        print("\nGuess The Number!\n")

        if r == guess:
            print("You Won!")

            break

        elif guess > r:
            print("Too High!\nGuess Again.")

        elif guess < r:
            print("Too Low!\nGuess Again.")

    elif play_game.choice.upper() == "QUIT":
        print("See You Later!")

        sleep(1)

        break

    else:
        print("Unknown Command!\nTry Again")
```

Or even better, you can generate the number before the run loop with the if/elif and then have a univerasal run loop, as you have the same code for guessing.

```py
# *ask for gamemode*

r = 0

if choice == "1":
    r = random.randint(1, 10)
elif choice == "2":
    r = random.randint(1, 50)
elif choice == "3":
    r = random.randint(1, 100)


print("\nGuess The Number!\n")
while run:
    guess = int(input("> "))

    if r == guess:
        print("You Won!")
        break

    elif guess > r:
        print("Too High!\nGuess Again.")

    elif guess < r:
        print("Too Low!\nGuess Again.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do. Here is the use case I understand from your question and the code:

1. generate a random number named "r"
2. acquire guess input (variable is named "guess") from the user
3. if r == guess, stop the game
4. if r != guess, ask another guess and return to step 2

Hence, you need to change the following:

- The variable "r" should be before the while loop, that is, `r = random.randint(..,..)` should be before the line `while run:`. The argument in `randint` should be decided according to the level, but, again, before the while loop!
- once the user has found `r`, that is, when `guess == r`, then you should set variable `run` to False.

Let me know if you manage to find a solution, otherwise I can send you a detailed script.

I propose this code:

```py
import random

level = input("""                                        Number Guessing Game
        Type 'Quit' To Exit The Game
Choose a Level:
    (1)Easy
    (2)Medium
    (3)Hard
""")

print("\nGuess The Number!\n")
run = True
if level == "1":
    r = random.randint(1, 10)

elif level == "2":
    r = random.randint(1, 50)

elif level == "3":
    r = random.randint(1, 100)

else:
    raise ValueError("incorrect level")

while run:
    guess = int(input("> "))

    if guess == r:
        print("You Won!")
        run = False

    elif guess > r:
        print("Too High!\nGuess Again.")

    elif guess < r:
        print("Too Low!\nGuess Again.")
```